# Dropbox: Unable to monitor dropbox folder

Tags: linux, dropbox, inotify

I'm using Dropbox on an Arch Linux System. Everything worked fine for months now, until today. When running Dropbox from command line, it prints the error message:

> `Unable to monitor entire Dropbox folder hierarchy. Please run "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p" and restart Dropbox to fix the problem.`

I don't like running terminal commands blindly without thinking about it, especially when running as `sudo`. So I'd really like to understand why Dropbox needs that fix, especially after running fine for months.

Comment: It *may* be because the Dropbox folders have got larger (number of files), or that other apps are using `inotify`. You can check your current value with `sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches`. Anyway the command recommended seems safe and not a high value (I have 524288). This is informative: https://askubuntu.com/questions/154255/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-out-of-inotify-watches

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact issue on Fedora 30. I tried the suggested command but it didn't work. Saw this answer and tried increasing inotify to 500000 instead of 100000 suggested. This worked for me.

```
sudo echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=500000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p
```